# array reduce amount value into string format

Tags: javascript

I have an array of items, where i need to get a string of each product price.

```js
const input = [{id: 1, amount: 20}, {id: 2, amount: 40}, {id: 3, amount: 90}]

const output = input?.reduce((acc, curr) => {
        acc += `$${curr.amount}+`;
        return acc;
      }, '')

console.log(output)
```

Expected output is $20+$40+$90

But when i am trying this code i am getting the sum as $150 and i don't want to have + at the last if there are no more items.

Comment: Why `reduce()`? This a classic example for `map()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to extract the values followed by a [join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) to create the string.

```
input.map(i => `$${i.amount}`).join('+')
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by linking to the MDN documentation for `map` and `join`, and template strings, and by also addressing the typo.

Comment: This isn't valid JavaScript (`->` should be `=>`)

Comment: Also, it does not produce the expected result. However, upvoted for its spirit.

Comment: You need to have `i.amount` otherwise you're just calling the default implementation of `.toString()` of the object

Comment: Thanks @Samathingamajig. I have fixed the issues you pointed out. I wrote the answer in a rush.

Comment: @Andy I have added the MDN docs. Good suggestion.

Answer (score 4):

Why [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)? This is a classic example for [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
const input = [{id: 1, amount: 20}, {id: 2, amount: 40}, {id: 3, amount: 90}]

const expression = input.map(
  ({ amount }) => `$${amount}`     // destructure the object, keep only .amount
).join('+');

console.log(expression);
```

Read about [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) in the JavaScript documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Use split, and your code almost works

```js
const input = [{id: 1, amount: 20}, {id: 2, amount: 40}, {id: 3, amount: 90}]

const output = input?.reduce((acc, curr) => {
        acc.push(curr.amount + "$");
        return acc;
      }, []).join("+")

console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const input = [{ id: 1, amount: 20 }, { id: 2, amount: 40 }, { id: 3, amount: 90 }]

const output = input?.slice(1).reduce((acc, curr) => {
    acc += `+$${curr.amount}`;
    return acc;
}, input.length ? `$${input[0].amount}` : '');

console.log(output)
```

with minimum manipulation

Answer (score 0):

To add to the answers, we can use the `currentIndex` in the callback function in `reduce` as the third argument.

```js
const input = [{id: 1, amount: 20}, {id: 2, amount: 40}, {id: 3, amount: 90}, {id: 4, amount: 55}]

const output = input?.reduce((acc, curr, index) => {
        acc += `$${curr.amount}`;
        if (index < input.length - 1) acc += '+'
        return acc;
      }, '')

console.log(output)
```

`